# How to implement efficient IP whitelist in gin-gonic/gin middleware

Tags: go, middleware, go-gin

I have an application which I need to restrict to a handful of IPs. I can write a middleware and return if request IP is not from allowed list, however I would like this process to be as efficient as possible. I.e. I would like to drop the connection as early as possible. What is the earliest stage I can drop connection, preferably with an HTTP response. 
I do not have control on host firewall or border firewall to filter traffic, and again, I won't be able to provide an HTTP response, even if I had control of firewall.

Also I would prefer if I could get a description of a life cycle of an HTTP request in gin.

Answer (score 5):

Add a middleware as Lansana described.

It's important that you declare it as early in the chain as possible.

```
r := gin.New()

whitelist := make(map[string]bool)
whitelist["127.0.0.1"] = true

r.Use(middleware.IPWhiteList(whitelist))
```

I'd write the middleware like this, if you're not in the whitelist, return an error that is appropriate, in the following snippet i'm returning a JSON error.

```
package middleware

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func IPWhiteList(whitelist map[string]bool) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if !whitelist[c.ClientIP()] {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusForbidden, gin.H{
                "status":  http.StatusForbidden,
                "message": "Permission denied",
            })
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please check my comment above, any information will be quite useful, specially HTTP request life cycle in gin.

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the [Gin documentation](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin)?

You can add middleware based on the examples in [this section](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#using-middleware). Use `router.Use()` to chain middleware. If you want it to be as efficient as possible, make it the first middleware in the chain, and use a data structure that allows O(1) read access to the IP's that are allowed.

For instance:

```
var myWhiteList map[string]bool = map[string]bool{
    "1.2.3.4": true,
    "4.3.2.1": true,
}

func main() {
    // Creates a router without any middleware by default
    r := gin.New()

    // Add whitelist middleware
    r.Use(middleware.IPWhitelist(myWhiteList))

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

The implementation of `middleware.IPWhitelist` can look something like this:

```
func IPWhiteList(whitelist map[string]bool) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    f := func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Get IP of this request
            ip := doSomething()

            // If the IP isn't in the whitelist, forbid the request.
            if !whitelist[ip] {
                w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
                w.Write([]byte("."))
                return
            }

            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }

        return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
    }

    return f
}
```

Comment: I shall be more detailed: remoteAddr is available as soon as TCP connection is established, however, my assumption is, first middleware gets to execute only when client is done sending complete HTTP request. In case client is posting a file, my first middleware with O(1) lookup will be executed after a couple of milliseconds, few  MBs of data transfer and a few thousands of CPU cycles atleast. So my question is what is the earliest stage a middleware can get control of request processing, and can reject request, preferably with a valid HTTP response code, saving those resources mentioned above

Comment: Or how Expect header should be handled? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate? If you want to get the RemoteAddr or get the IP some other way, do it in the `doSomething()` function I added in the middleware above. That is where you can get the IP address or unique request ID, however you want to do that.

Comment: doSomething() is invoked after client is done sending all data (request header + request body). I would prefer to be able to decide if I want to process request, right after request headers have been received, but before request body is transmitted. This will save a lot of time and other resources. I hope the problem is clear now. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't think Golang is the right tool to solve that problem, then. You should be doing this at the DNS level, perhaps in a firewall or load balancer, not in your Go code. If your intent here is to prevent DDoS, you DEFINITELY do not want to do it in Go. No matter what sort of middleware you add, all that have to do is completely flood your pipes and your server will still be put to a halt. Look into something like CloudFlare; they are built specifically to prevent DDoS as they will act as a proxy in front of your services and prevent any malicious requests from reaching your services.

Comment: To demonstrate what I mean, go ahead and add the middleware example I showed you, and use a load testing tool built in Go, such as [Bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier), and hit your local server as hard as you can. You will see that eventually, even with a whitelist middleware, the server will have so many connections open that it can't handle them anymore and the same result occurs: a denial of service. You can't prevent DDoS at application level.